# SVG rendering in C# with SVG library always fills shapes with black

Tags: c#, image, svg

I'm using the Svg.Core library (version 3.0.49.2) to render SVGs (defined in strings) to PNG images.  No matter what I do, any shape seems to be rendered with a black stroke and a black fill.

Here's the code I'm using for a simple rectangle, as an example:

```
var svgString = @"<svg width=""300"" height=""300"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink""><rect x=""5"" y=""5"" height=""90"" width=""50"" fill=""#ef0000"" stroke=""#00ef00"" /></svg>";
var svgDocument = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgString);
var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Png);
```

which ends up rendering a rectangle of the correct height and width, but all black:

[image: black rectangle as rendered]

I've seen a number of posts that mention various versions of inlining styles, but regardless of whether I'm using a style="" approach or a fill="", the problem continues.  Also seems to happen without fill color specified or using standard color names instead of RGB values.

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Just one question: don't you need to encode the octothorpe (#) inside the strings?

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta, but I don't believe so - only for URLs, not for strings within code.  Also I've tried with standard names like "green", "red" and "transparent" with no change

Comment: As an update, for anyone wrestling with the same challenge, it *looks* like the SVG library ignores everything that is in the SVG definition for fills and strokes.  If you put the following around it:  `svgDoc.Color = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.StopColor = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);
svgDoc.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen);` , you will get colors in the SVG.  Still digging in on this.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have come up with here is from the comment earlier.  If you put the following around it: svgDoc.Color = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen); svgDoc.StopColor = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen); svgDoc.Stroke = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen); svgDoc.Fill = new SvgColourServer(Color.DarkGreen); , you will get colors in the SVG.  Posting this as the answer in case anyone runs into this issue down the road.